# Is $d_p$ an extended metric for real sequences ($\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$)?

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning real analysis and my book says "Indeed, no $d_p$ defines a distance function on the entire $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ (Why?)".

$d_p: \ell^p \text{x} \ell^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}+$ is defined as $d_p((x_m),(y_m)):= \left(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_i-y_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$.

I was thinking about why, and thought that the answer was that the $d_p$ between two sequences could obviously be infinity, whereas a distance must be in $\mathbb{R}+$. However, if that constraint was relaxed, and $d_p$ was allowed to be $\infty$, then would any $d_p$ then fulfill all the requirements of a metric? Some googling shows that this concept is called an "extended metric space" ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Extended_metrics)).

So my question is: is any $d_p$ an extended metric for real sequences ($\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$)?

It seems to me that this is true: two sequences have distance 0 iff they are the same sequence. The distance function is symmetric. And I don't know how to prove that the triangle inequality is true, but I can't think of any examples that violate it! Nor was I able to find any previous instances of someone asking this question online.

Comment: Please state the definition of $d_p.$ Since you say your book refers to it, there muwt be a definition of it in your book. But we don't know what your book is.

Comment: oops, sorry it's hard to tell which terms are canon and which ones are book-specific. Edited to include definition.

Comment: This is just the usual $l^p$ norm (or rather distance) on $l^p(\mathbb{N})$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#ℓp_spaces.

Comment: Yes, it's the usual $l^p$ norm (or distance). I was wondering if it's also an extended distance for any real sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common definition of a metric on a set $X$ is a function $d : X\times X \to \Bbb R$ with the properties

- for all $x, y \in X, d(x, y) \ge 0$.
- for all $x, y \in X, d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$.
- for all $x, y \in X, d(x,y) = d(y, x)$.
- for all $x, y, z \in X, d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x,z)$.

(It is highly common to explicitly exclude negatives from the codomain, instead of just saying those values cannot be in the image, as I have done here. That is a trivial difference in definition, and I see both variations regularly.)

As you've noticed, $d_p$ satisfies everything except that the codomain (and image) of $d_p$ includes $\infty$. It is perfectly reasonable to modify the definition of a metric to $d: X\times X \to \Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, while modifying the Triangle Inequality to

- for all $x, y, z \in X$, if $d(x,y) < \infty$ and $d(y, z) < \infty$, then $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$.
- for all $x,y,z \in X$, if $d(x,y) < \infty$ and $d(y,z) = \infty$, then $d(x, z) = \infty$.

Because topology is determined by how $d$ acts when it is small, not large, this still defines a topology with the same general metric space behaviors on $\Bbb R^\omega$. Pretty much everything you can do or say about an ordinary metric, you can still do or say about this metric, with only exceptions being statements that specifically exclude $\infty$ as a distance.

One way to understand this is to note that if $d$ is an arbitrary metric on $X$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can define another metric $d_\epsilon$ by $d_\epsilon = \min\{d(x,y), \epsilon\}$. You can confirm that $d_\epsilon$ satisfies all the conditions listed to be a metric. But the interesting thing is that the exact same sets are open under $d_\epsilon$ as are under $d$. The exact same sets are compact, the exact same sets are connected. The exact same sequences are Cauchy, converge, and to the exact same limits. The only difference is that even when $X$ is unbounded under $d$, it is always bounded under $d_\epsilon$.

But this is true even if $d$ is an "infinite metric". $d_\epsilon$ will be a normal metric with the same topological properties as $d$.